# Code compiles in Terminal but not in XCode with external class file

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, terminal

I have a code that runs fine in the Terminal with

```
g++ -o test main.cpp
```

But in Xcode for example the code in maylass.h file with the following lines fails:

```
class database{
int size;
dataset *set;
public:
void init();
void insert(string name, unsigned int age);
void show();
void clear();
database();
~database();
void operator+(const database & b);
};
```

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDfjl.png)

I am using Xcode 4.2 on OSX 10.7.5.

`dataset` is defined in the main function in main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct dataset {
    string name;
    unsigned int age;
};
#include "myclass.cpp"
```

`stream` ist a stream from the std namespace.

Comment: Where are `dataset` and `string` defined?

Comment: Please have a look at the edited question.

Comment: (I haven't used plain C in a while but) Should it be `struct dataset *set;`?

Comment: It´s supposed to be C++. No, I think `struct dataset {`is fine. It compiles fine in the Terminal anyway. It only does not build in XCode.

Comment: Ah, right...automatic typedefs in C++.

Comment: My guess is that your XCode project contains both .cpp files, and you would see exactly the same error if you executed `g++ -c myclass.cpp` in the terminal. `#include`-ing .cpp files is not the way you normally do things.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the reason. But how can I have an external class if not in a .cpp file? Is there a way around that?

Comment: If you want to keep your `#include "myclass.cpp"` structure, you should be able to select myclass.cpp in Xcode's Project Navigator and then **uncheck** the Target membership for it in the File Inspector.  That should prevent it from being compiled on its own.

Comment: I have solved it by only adding a header file instead of a header file and a .cpp file. I have put the external functions from the class into the header file as well.

Comment: @PhillipMills: I have just tried your approach as well. It works! brilliant! thanks!!